# OpenFileDialog issue with release resource

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

i have this problem with OpenFileDialog in win form ..

```
private void btnAllegato_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                string path = string.Empty;

                openFileDialog1.Title = "Seleziona richiestaIT (PDF)..";
                openFileDialog1.Filter = ("PDF (.pdf)|*.pdf");
                openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
                openFileDialog1.FileName = "";


                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    //salva l'intero path
                    path = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                    //nome file + estensione
                    string temp = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;

                    //elimina l'estensione del file con IgnoreCase -> case Unsensitive
                    temp = Regex.Replace(temp, ".pdf", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    //datatime + replace
                    string timenow = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();

                    //replace data da gg//mm/aaaa  ss:mm:hh  ----->  ad   gg-mm-aaaa_ss-mm-hh  
                    timenow = timenow.Replace(":", "-").Replace("/", "-");//.Replace(" ", " ");     

                    //effettua una copia dal path origine alla cartella nel NAS
                    _url = @"\\192.168.5.7\dati\SGI\GESTIONE IT\RichiesteIT\" + temp + timenow + ".pdf";

                    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

                    System.IO.File.Copy(path, _url);


                    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

At first run ... all is ok... 
But with second click to btn ... The process go to loop.. OpenFileDialog is open but is total white... 
[image]

I think that is a problem of dispose resource.. but i don't know how resolve it.

...
...
***@EDIT***

after several attempts ... I realized that the problem is after I clik on botton *Inserisci>>*. 
Run good first time but when i click to second time on ... *btnAllegato* after btnInserisci i have loop process.

[image]
Code btnInserisci :

```
        private void btnInserisci_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((_IDRichiedente != -1) && (_data != string.Empty) && (_url != string.Empty))
            {
                //messageBox
                MessageBox.Show(_url);
                QueryAssist qa = new QueryAssist();
                string query = "INSERT INTO RICHIESTA_IT(ID_Risorsa, descrizione_richiesta, modulo_pdf, data_richiesta) VALUES('" + _IDRichiedente + "', '" + txtBreveDescrizione.Text + "', '" + _url + "', '" + _data + "');";
                MessageBox.Show(query);

                qa.runQuery(query);
                // qa.runQuery("INSERT INTO RICHIESTA_IT (ID_Risorsa, data_richiesta) VALUES ('" + _IDRichiedente + "','" + _data + "');");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selezionare il richiedente,data o allegato!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

where `private int _IDRichiedente = -1;
        private string _data = String.Empty;
        private string _url = string.Empty;` is a fields of class.

QueryAssist is my personal class that create a connection , run a query and disconnect . 
Code :

```
    class QueryAssist
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _OleDBconnection;

    public QueryAssist()
    {
        this._OleDBconnection = null;
    }

    //riferimento di connessione al db
    private bool connectionDB()
    {
        string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=\"\\\\192.168.5.7\\dati\\Scambio\\Sviluppo\\Impostazioni temporanea db Censimento\\CensimentoIT.accdb\"";
        try
        {
            _OleDBconnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connection);
            _OleDBconnection.Open();
            return true;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void disconnectDB()
    {
        try
        {
            _OleDBconnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }

    public System.Data.DataTable runQuery(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connectionDB())
            {
                System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand sqlQuery = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, _OleDBconnection);
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery);
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                disconnectDB();
                return dataTable;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;

    }

    public int countRowsQueryResult(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connectionDB())
            {
                System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand sqlQuery = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, _OleDBconnection);
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery);
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                disconnectDB();
                return dataTable.Rows.Count;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return -1;

    }
}
```

}

Sorry for my english

Comment: Do you have any `GDI+` or `Win32` api codes  in your application?

Comment: only windows form...

Comment: do you have [STAThread] attribute above Main of your program.cs ?

Comment: A deadlock like this is likely to occur when the Main() entrypoint of your program is missing the [STAThread] attribute or you run this code on a worker thread.  A wonky shell extension installed on your machine can cause it as well.

Comment: [STAThread] is present  
[link image](http://postimg.org/image/bc5kamgcd/) ...

Comment: now i realized that ...the function `btnAllegato_Click` run always and good when i click... But i have the loop process when i click on another button(Inserisci >>  in image) in this form that create and execute a query to db. First run is ok ... But when i click on btnAllegato after query i have a loop..
[form](http://postimg.org/image/q3bi4p9kz/)  ... my code for button Inserisci [btnInserisci](http://postimg.org/image/saoqrub55/) 
I don't know why but loop is only after query to db is ok and next i click to btnAllegato..

Answer (score 0):

Take it out of the 'Using' statement. Change

```
using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog())
```

to

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
```

Just see if that makes a difference. If so, the problem is with the disposing of the statement.

Comment: i haven't difference .. :(

Comment: Then I would say it is not the OpenFileDialog itself. I agree with the person who said to try and copy the file local and see if that makes a differenc. You can also try commenting out everything after the dialog OK (just put in a message box to show the file name), and slowly uncomment things until you can narrow it down a bit more.

Comment: In local i have the same problem. 
The problem is (in my opinion).. one istant of Open Dialog... because i haven't the possibility to click ok or other... because windows is total white .. is go to loop...

Answer (score 0):

I think the File.Copy might be hanging up. Try the same code with a local file path like "c:\filename.pdf" as the URL.

```
//Crea il nome del file di destinazione
string _url = string.Format(@"c:\{0}{1}.pdf", temp, timenow);
```

If this works correctly, the problem will lie with the connection to the NAS.

Comment: It may be the connection to the network resource, indeed... but `File.Copy` should not be the culprit there... it is synchronous, so if it hanged, it should hang before even giving the option to click the button again.

Comment: @Jcl: I agree. I'm wildly guessing this first try went through ok, and the connection was lost when retrying.

Comment: isn't a problem of connection to NAS. In local I have the same problem. 
In this program i have the sames code in two different form (used by showDialog mode) ... one run good but this go to loop ... 
unbelievable...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is commonly found when your application doesn't use a single-thread apartment COM model.

Generally, for WinForms, on your `Main` method in `Program.cs`, you'll need to have a `[STAThread]` attribute, something like:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
...
```

If you don't have that, and you are sure you don't need MTA, you can just add it there.

Otherwise, I have this utility code (which I'm sure I didn't write, I just copied it from somewhere but can't really give credit, it's been in my "winforms utility class" for a while) for common dialogs, which creates a new thread using STA and invokes the dialog there:

```
public class DialogInvoker
{
   public CommonDialog InvokeDialog;
   private Thread InvokeThread;
   private DialogResult InvokeResult;

   public DialogInvoker(CommonDialog dialog)
   {
      InvokeDialog = dialog;
      InvokeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(InvokeMethod));
      InvokeThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
      InvokeResult = DialogResult.None;
   }

   public DialogResult Invoke()
   {
      InvokeThread.Start();
      InvokeThread.Join();
      return InvokeResult;
   }

   private void InvokeMethod()
   {
      InvokeResult = InvokeDialog.ShowDialog();
   }
}
```

To use it, change:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

For:

```
if ((new DialogInvoker(openFileDialog1)).Invoke() == DialogResult.OK)
```

Comment: ![image](http://s14.postimg.org/o3jqh4q4h/img_Thread.png) STAThread is present ... to understanding what u said ... I shoul know thread - threading application etc.. ?! 
In any case i have two OpenFileDialog in my program.. with sames code.. 
One run good but this ... go to loop ..

Comment: now i realized that ...the function `btnAllegato_Click` run always and good when i click... But i have the loop process when i click on another button(Inserisci >>  in image) in this form that create and execute a query to db. First run is ok ... But when i click on btnAllegato after query i have a loop..
[form](http://postimg.org/image/q3bi4p9kz/)  ... my code for button Inserisci [btnInserisci](http://postimg.org/image/saoqrub55/) 
I don't know why but loop is only after query to db is ok and next i click to btnAllegato..

Comment: I don't know what `QueryAssist ` is

Comment: How i can poste the code ? is too big for an image, is too big for comment :/ ... 
QuertAssist is a personal class that open a Connection to Db... 
method RunQuery(query) return a DataTable sames  query result..

Comment: If you believe it is pertinent to the question, edit your question and add that information

Answer (score -1):

Io suggerirei di provare così: Using non si utilizza con le dialog

```
try
{

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    string path = string.Empty;

    openFileDialog1.Title = "Seleziona richiestaIT (PDF)..";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = ("PDF (.pdf)|*.pdf");
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
    openFileDialog1.FileName = "";


    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        //salva l'intero path
        path = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        //Togli l'estensione dal file
        string temp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        //Crea un nome univoco usando data e ora
        string timenow = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_ss-mm-hh");


        //Crea il nome del file di destinazione
        string _url = string.Format(@"\\192.168.5.7\dati\SGI\GESTIONE IT\RichiesteIT\{0}{1}.pdf", temp, timenow);

        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        File.Copy(path, _url);


        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: This is an English knowledge-sharing site. Most people here don't speak Italian, and therefor won't understand what you are saying. Please answer in English.

Comment: Sorry for the italian line, but the question was made by an italian, and my answer was "I suggest to try this" :)